# ingress in AKS for API

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, microservices, azure-aks

I'm trying to deploy an ASP-Net Core API and make it available from outside cluster trough an ingress.  I have followed the steps mentioned in the [learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli). All the steps are working fine, however, I'm unable to access my ingress on the route /api/opportunities/. Below I'm describing my K8S files, might I be missing something?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: opportunities-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: opportunities-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: opportunities-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: opportunities-api
          image: mycontainer.azurecr.io/opportunities-api:{BUILD_NO}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:  
  name: opportunities-api  
spec:
  ports:
  - port : 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    component: opportunities-api
  type: ClusterIP

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: opportunities-api
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: opportunities-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that host field is missing in above ingress yaml. Did you try adding **.spec.rules.host** in the ingress yaml as below and see if it helps?
As per the nginx document, it is one of the [restrictions](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/#restrictions).

Also, if AKS v>=1.24, then can you check what is the value set for annotation **service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path** in  **ingress controller service**. It should be **/healthz** as discussed in [AKS Ingress-Nginx ingress controller failing to route by host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247903/aks-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-failing-to-route-by-host/75250323#75250323)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: opportunities-api
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: abc.com #your host name here
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: opportunities-api
            port:
              number: 80
```